# C++ Hashing a user defined type for use in unordered map - Can I Create one long string then use the default hash<string>?

Tags: c++, hash

C++ Hashing a user defined type for use in unordered map - Can I Create one long string then use the default hash?
Like the title says, 
would this work?

```
struct Key
{
  std::string first;
  std::string second;
  int         third;

  bool operator==(const Key &other) const
  { return (first == other.first
            && second == other.second
            && third == other.third);
  }
};

struct KeyHasher
{
  std::size_t operator()(const Key& k) const
  {
    using std::size_t;
    using std::hash;
    using std::string;

    return ((hash<string>()(k.first + k.second +(std::to_string(k.third));
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::unordered_map<Key,std::string,KeyHasher> m6 = {
    { {"John", "Doe", 12}, "example"},
    { {"Mary", "Sue", 21}, "another"}
  };
}
```

It would just use the default hash on a long string right?

Comment: What's wrong with `return hash(k.first)^hash(k.second)^k.third`  ??

Comment: Or probably better: `return (hash(k.first)<<16) ^(hash(k.second)<<8)^k.third`